# bitcoin-cli WIF from xpriv, descriptor outputs clarity

Tags: bitcoin-cli, regtest, output-script-descriptors, wallet-import-format, private-key-format

## Questions

1. Is it possible for the `bitcoin-cli` command to extract WIFs from a ranged descriptor with a derivation path?
2. If a descriptor is ranged it **must have** a xpriv key?
3. If a descriptor has a xpriv it **must have** a derivation path?
4. If yes to 2,3 than the only other type would be a simple desc(wif) which would have neither a derivation path nor range?

I understand this is probably a bad idea (defeats the purpose of descriptors), but for curiosity reasons I'm asking.

## Goal

My goal is to learn more about descriptors/WIFs/etc for testing alongside with the bitcoin-cli.

Comment: As far as Bitcoin Core is concerned, WIFs *are* the way private keys are encoded. If you're talking about "from" private keys, you must have some other encoding in mind. I don't believe any other encodings are supported besides WIF (and xprvs).

Comment: I think my confusion is/was mainly around descriptors. You typically wouldn't be able to grab a single key or wif from a descriptor output (or at least you typically wouldn't want to do this because then you lose what makes a descriptor a descriptor)?. I was given a key for a tr descriptor which now seems unusual I guess?. I'm wondering how you would one start with descriptor and then give someone a wif to a tr output? (updated question)

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is possible to create a Wallet Import Format (WIF) from a private key using the bitcoin-cli command. Here's an example of how you can do it:

- [step.1] Generate a new private key:

```bash
bitcoin-cli -regtest getnewaddress
bitcoin-cli -regtest dumpprivkey <address>
```

- [step.2] Convert the private key to WIF format:

```bash
$ bitcoin-cli -regtest dumpprivkey <private_key>
```

Replace <private_key> with the actual private key you generated in step 2.

The `dumpprivkey` command will output the corresponding WIF for the given private key. The WIF can be used for various purposes, such as importing the key into a wallet or performing other operations.

Using the `bitcoin-cli` command with the `-regtest` flag ensures that you are operating in the regression test mode, which is suitable for testing purposes.

By following these steps, you should be able to easily generate `regtest WIFs` for testing without relying on external programs or libraries.

Comment: @PieterWuille There was a typo in the text, I fixed it, what does it have to do with Ai?